# Windows Xbox Game Bar won't record video on windows 11

Tags: recording, xbox-game-bar

I'm trying to use Win+G or Win+Alt+R to use the Xbox game bar to record my screen in Windows 11. I can open the game bar and the capture widget, but the button to record video (the little circle) is grayed out. I have a Firefox window open so it should be possible, and I can do this in a different laptop that's also running Windows 11. I even went into gpedit (after installing a hacked windows 11 version of it) and made sure Windows game recording is enabled.

I couldn't find any solutions to this anywhere else; everything I could find was either fixes for when the game bar won't open at all (which is not the problem I'm having) or saying that you need to have a window open and you can't just record your desktop or file explorer (also not my problem). If anyone has any ideas what the problem here is, they'd be greatly appreciated!